# Nested throttle for API in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-grape, throttling

I know there is a lot of gems around throttling API requests in rails, but the problem is their structure is pretty flat - I mean you cannot apply another rule based on other rule happening. Here is the example:

`throttle max: 100, per: 1.day`

cool, but what if I want to reduce the number of those requests after reaching 100 per day to for example 10 per hour?

so something like:

`throttle max: 100, per: 1.day do
   throttle max: 10, per: 1.hour
end`

how to achieve that with the use of existing gems avoiding custom solutions as much as possible?